# Should I use a LIKE query for these ActiveRecord relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a single web page form user interface with 2 sets of checkboxes. With set 1 checkboxes, I can check off what Trainers I would like ("Jason", "Alexandra, etc.) With set 2 checkboxes, I can check off what animals I would like to see ("Tigers", "Bears", etc.)  Once I submit the form with these options, I get back a list of zoos that match the criteria (let's assume all the trainers work at all the zoos and all the animals are at all the zoos for discussion's sake)

We'll be running our database query by "name" (e.g., search using trainer names and animal names, NOT database ids)

Let's say we are using a Postgres database that has hundreds of thousands of rows (if not millions).

1. Is it more efficient to search using an "ILIKE" query or is it better to do a standard join query (e.g., `Zoo.includes(:animals, :trainers).where("animals.name = ? and trainers.name = ?", animal_names, trainer_names)`?
2. Is there a better way than what I just showed in #1 above?

*model setup*

```
class Zoo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :animals, through: zoo_animals
  has_many :trainers, through: zoo_trainers
  has_many :zoo_trainers
  has_many :zoo_animals
end  

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zoos, through :zoo_animals
  has_many :zoo_animals
end  

class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zoos, through :zoo_trainers 
  has_many :zoo_trainers
end  

class ZooAnimal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
  belongs_to :zoo
end

class ZooTrainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zoo
  belongs_to :trainer
end
```

EDIT: let's suppose I don't have access to the database ID's.

Comment: Why not return IDs from the form?

Comment: Good point, suppose I could do that too.

Comment: But I still want to answer the question - let's suppose I don't have access to the database id's.

Comment: What `LIKE` or `ILIKE` query do you need? Would you be searching for '%Jason%' or 'Jason%' or just 'Jason' or something else?

Comment: Both - basically any option containing a substring "Jason"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE '%Jason%'` is much less efficient than querying for the exact string 'Jason' (or querying for an ID), because while exact comparisons and some uses of `LIKE` can use an index on the column being queried, [`LIKE` with a pattern beginning with a wildcard can't use an index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning).

However, performance doesn't sound like the most important consideration here. `LIKE %Jason%` will still probably be fast enough on a reasonably sized database under reasonable load. If the application really needs to search for things by substring (which implies that a search might have multiple results), that requirement can't be met by simple equality.

There are an endless number of higher-powered solutions to searching text, including Postgres built-in full-text search and external solutions like Elasticsearch. Without specific requirements for scaling I'd go with `LIKE` until it started to slow down and only then invest in something more complicated.